# Interlocking and joints for 3D printed structure, tips&types

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, rapid-prototyping

I'm a student and I need to 3D print a structure for a research. I know nothing about mechanic parts, joints and interlocking so I hope someone could help.

[image: Here you can see the model of the structure I have to print, in white] The diameter of the whole structure is about 44 cm while the diameter of the tubular has to be 1.5/2 cm.
I need to divide the structure into different pieces:

- The part that fits the black tubular: I can't put it there from the top but it has to be 2 different pieces that I can tighten with a bolt in order to assemble and disassemble.
- Then, I have to divide the arms from the little circular "plate"

I know nothing about interlocking and parts.